# Python name of class not defined

Tags: python, object

[image]

I do not understand why the name `Queue` is not defined (Picture above).

From the code examples I have looked at I should be able to create a `Queue`-Object with `queue = Queue(5)` but it keeps giving me an error

Comment: Show code and other textual information as properly formatted text in the question, not as comment, image or external link.

Comment: It's *not* defined at the point where you call `Queue`. The name is not defined until after the body of the `class` statement has been evaluated and the metaclass has been called.

Comment: BTW, welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour], and check out [ask] if you want tips.

Answer (score 2):

You are calling `Queue` within your `Queue` class. I think you meant to call it outside of it. Unindenting the line `queue = Queue(5)` should solve your problem.

Comment: Ah I come from Java and python indents confuse me. I did not notice I was still in the object